# php add values and print

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql table formatted like this:

YES NO
1     0
0     1
1     0

and I'm trying to add up the yes and the no columns, then print the result. My current code looks like this:

```
$sql = "select sum(yes) from votes";
$sql = "select sum(no) from votes";
```

Any help?

EDITS: (responses to comments) 
YES and NO are INT. 
I get no error. It's just a blank screen. 
I do not echo the results. The code above is the only code that has to do with this part.

Comment: Any error you are getting? or what result it's showing?. As per your code you `$sql` variable is only going to have the sum of "no"

Comment: what is the data type of the YES & NO column? It should be numeric data type and make sure the case type(upper/lower) in the query...

Comment: select sum(YES) as yes ,sum(NO) as no from votes

Comment: Where do you echo the results from the SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to sum both columns needed:

```
SELECT SUM(yes) AS yesSum, SUM(no) AS noSum FROM votes
```